# is it possible to import with variable in react?

Tags: reactjs, import, lazy-evaluation

first, i'm sorry my english is not good

i have a problem in React
i want to 'import' with viriable, not directly typing url

like this

```
//normal version
const mainpage = React.lazy(()=>import('src/pages/main/MainPage'))


//and i want to like this
const url = 'src/pages/main/MainPage'
const mainpage = React.lazy(()=>import(url))
```

but this not work cause Cannot find module

Do you have any solution that import without dircetly typing url?

Because, Paths (like url, module, path then saved module) should be loaded form database and use it

Comment: Which bundler are you using? The reason for this is bundlers like webpack need to statically analyse the code (without actually running it) to detect where code is split. The way the bundler does it is it loads the raw source code and scans for the `import` lines and then extracts the containing string at compile time. Generally, you can't really do this if a static bundler is in play unless the bundler is very clever. Im not sure any of them will do it tbh. Whats the use case?

Comment: Yes, seconding @adsy, you will need those to be static strings - so no, it is not possible to my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think there are no solution like this proplem,but I'm asking if there is a way I haven't found. When i use 'JSP', i load this paths from db, in controller. and this is work because controller return string type. my customer want this function and they want also use react. so i find way that load url from db and import module in react but i can't find solution